# JavaScript array slice edits main array

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I have the following code, and as of my knowledge Array.slice() is suppose to make a new copy of the main array, but it is not. As you can see, I am editing array **"b"** and it is modifying the main array **"a"**, which is not what I want.

```js
let a = [ { "a": true }, { "a": true }, { "a": true } ];
let b = a.slice(1, 2);
b[0].b = false;
console.log(a);
```

It would really help me if someone could give me a hint on how to make a copy from the main array and then edit it without modifying the main array. Thank you

**Edit (Solution):**

```js
function copy(obj) {
  return Object.assign({}, obj);
}

let a = [ { "a": true }, { "a": true }, { "a": true } ];
let b = a.slice(1, 2).map(copy);
b[0].b = false;
console.log(a);
```

credit: [Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/ryan)

Comment: It’s not the array; it’s the object itself. `b[0] === a[1]`. If you were to write `b[0] = { a: true, b: false };`, for example – changing the array instead of a value it contains – `a` wouldn’t change.

Comment: @Ryan ohh ok, then what is the proper way to copy an array of objects ?

Comment: To copy one plain object, you can use `Object.assign({}, obj)`, so here `function copy(obj) { return Object.assign({}, obj); } let b = a.slice(1, 2).map(copy);`

Comment: @Ryan it's not working, still same result

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/xxnofdkf/

Comment: @Ryan Look at this - https://jsfiddle.net/j0pay195/

Comment: found the err -> missing "{}, obj", thanks so much